# iOS: Will bundle file 's absolute path change after backup and other operation ? how can a get bundle file's relative path?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bundle

I want to asking a question about file 's absolute path in iOS.

I have lots of icon file in a bundle in my app, say it here: icons.bundle.

I have a photo browser to show user to choose these icon to represent their task, so I need remember the icon in database,

I got the icon path into a array by:

```
iconList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"icons.bundle"];
```

After check the string in iconList, I found they are absolute path like this(in simulator):

```
/Users/zhangjeef/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/945B3BD0-B44A-4836-9FDA-8DCCB9396F32/ShiftScheduler.app/jobicons.bundle/100-coffee.png
```

My question is, if I remember this full path in database, will it change after user backup/recovery application from iTune ?
Will this UUID change after I upgrade application ?

```
945B3BD0-B44A-4836-9FDA-8DCCB9396F32
```

Then, how can a get bundle file's relative path ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the `iconList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"icons.bundle"];` will return a relative path, so it's safe to use just that even after backup / recovery / update.

Comment: Sorry, this function actually return a absolute path: this is NSLog from my app:
  "/Users/zhangjeef/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/2F1191A7-8794-442A-8211-7FE4ED70488F/ShiftScheduler.app/jobicons.bundle/52-pine-tree.png",
    "/Users/zhangjeef/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/2F1191A7-8794-442A-8211-7FE4ED70488F/ShiftScheduler.app/jobicons.bundle/53-house.png",
    "/Users/zhangjeef/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/2F1191A7-8794-442A-8211-7FE4ED70488F/ShiftScheduler.app/jobicons.bundle/70-tv.png",

Comment: this function will return a correct path, you don't even have to care about it, try deleting your app right now from your simulator/device, redeploy, the path will be different, and it'll return correct path for you. That is what I meant, by relative, I meant, it'll relative to your app. Also, this is read only, you can't change anything inside this with your code.

Comment: I mean this UUID will change, 2F1191A7-8794-442A-8211-7FE4ED70488F

Answer (score 2):

I finally use this method in NSString to get the abstract path and store it in my data base.

`NSString theShortPath = [fullPathString lastPathComponent];`

When I want to get the full path, I use

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jobicons.bundle/%@", theShortPath] ofType:nil];`

So I don't need remember the full path.

Comment: That is the best way of doing it. It is dangerous to rely on expecting the full path to be unchanging